# How to convert this HQL to DetachedCriteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, orm, hql

This HQL statement, when executed produces this the following result:

```
select t, count(s) from Submission s right join s.Topics as t GROUP BY t.Id

result[0]
    [0] topic_id, topic_name, ... 
    [1] 10

result[1]
    [0] topic_id, topic_name, ... 
    [1] 12
     .
result[n]
    [0] topic_id, topic_name, ... 
    [1] 19
```

This DetachedCriteria API produces almost similar result but without loading the topic

```
ProjectionList PrjList = Projections.ProjectionList();
PrjList.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Topics"), "t");
PrjList.Add(Projections.Count("Id"));

DetachedCriteria Filter = DetachedCriteria.For<Submission>();
Filter.CreateCriteria("Topics", "t", JoinType.RightOuterJoin);
Filter.SetProjection(PrjList);

result[0]
    [0] null
    [1] 10

result[1]
    [0] null
    [1] 12
     .
result[n]
    [0] null
    [1] 19
```

For some reason nhibernate refuses to create topic objects for the result set but it does for the HQL query. Why is that?

Comment: You trying to GroupProperty a class, but not a property. I afraid you should group each of the properties you have in Topics to ProjectionList. In this case I would make a method extension that will add each property of calling class to grouping.

Comment: NHibernate, using HQL queries, is capable of doing what I'm trying here. I just want to find out the way to do the same thing using the Criteria API. What you're suggesting however will require transformation which I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Have a looked at Detached Criteria on Ayende's blog on http://ayende.com/blog/tags/nhibernate?page=3 It gives you a very detailed step by step guide on left outer joins and group by HQL aswell as the mapping behind.

Comment: Please post relevant code here, links may become broken (especially links like the one you used, it's a listing page with offset).

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderIDsContainingCurrentSku = DetachedCriteria.For<OrderItem>()
    .Add<OrderItem>(x=>x.Product.SKU==sku)
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Order.id"));
var skusOfProductsAppearingInOrdersContainingCurrentSku = DetachedCriteria.For<OrderItem>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty("Product.id"))
    .AddOrder(NHibernate.Criterion.Order.Desc(Projections.Count("Order.id")))
    .Add<OrderItem>(x=>x.Product.SKU!=sku)
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Order.id", orderIDsContainingCurrentSku))
    .SetMaxResults(15);
var recommended = _session.CreateCriteria<Product>()
    .SetFetchMode<Product>(x => x.Descriptors, FetchMode.Join)
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("id", skusOfProductsAppearingInOrdersContainingCurrentSku))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Product>();
```

And here is the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT this_.SKU                 as SKU1_1_,
   this_.ProductName         as ProductN2_1_1_,
   this_.BasePrice           as BasePrice1_1_,
   this_.WeightInPounds      as WeightIn4_1_1_,
   this_.DateAvailable       as DateAvai5_1_1_,
   this_.EstimatedDelivery   as Estimate6_1_1_,
   this_.AllowBackOrder      as AllowBac7_1_1_,
   this_.IsTaxable           as IsTaxable1_1_,
   this_.DefaultImageFile    as DefaultI9_1_1_,
   this_.AmountOnHand        as AmountO10_1_1_,
   this_.AllowPreOrder       as AllowPr11_1_1_,
   this_.DeliveryMethodID    as Deliver12_1_1_,
   this_.InventoryStatusID   as Invento13_1_1_,
   descriptor2_.SKU          as SKU3_,
   descriptor2_.DescriptorID as Descript1_3_,
   descriptor2_.DescriptorID as Descript1_4_0_,
   descriptor2_.Title        as Title4_0_,
   descriptor2_.Body         as Body4_0_
FROM   Products this_
   left outer join ProductDescriptors descriptor2_
     on this_.SKU = descriptor2_.SKU
WHERE  this_.SKU in (SELECT   top 15 this_0_.SKU as y0_
FROM     OrderItems this_0_
WHERE    not (this_0_.SKU = 'Binoculars2' /* @p0 */)
    and this_0_.OrderID in (SELECT this_0_0_.OrderID as y0_
        FROM   OrderItems this_0_0_
        WHERE  this_0_0_.SKU = 'Binoculars2' /* @p1 */)
            GROUP BY this_0_.SKU
            ORDER BY count(this_0_.OrderID) desc)
```

See http://ayende.com/blog/4315/building-a-recommendation-engine-in-nhibernate on how it is done!